# How to make an element reference a StaticResource Storyboard in XAML (instead of the storyboard referencing the element)

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, mvvm, storyboard

I am reading the MSDN Animation tutorial, and it describes the following steps to apply a storyboard to an element:

1. Create the Storyboard;
2. Specify its target element name with the `TargetName` property;
3. (Specify the target property);
4. (Add an event trigger to start the animation);

I see a conceptual problem, from which derives my difficulty, that's this:

> I have a one-to-one relationship between storyboard and element, and this relationship is defined in the storyboard. Then, how could I create ONE storyboard, and conditionally apply it to more than one element, triggering the animation FROM THE ELEMENT ITSELF (via Binding / Triggers, I suppose).

My intended use case is to mimmick a panel of leds (a stackpanel of ellipses) where each led can be in one of four logical states: on, off, blinking fast, and blinking slow (pretty much like ethernet routers do). Then, I'd create the animations `BlinkingSlow` and `BlinkingFast`, which would then be triggered when my ViewModel entered the respective logical states. Then I could just care about behavior in the ViewModel and let the View take care of itself, with proper triggering and reuse of a few StaticResource Storyboards.

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:blinking"
        x:Class="blinking.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Background="{x:Null}"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Window.Resources>
        <System:Double x:Key="Diameter">40</System:Double>
        <Color x:Key="RedOn">Red</Color>
        <Color x:Key="RedOff">#FF570000</Color>
        <Storyboard x:Key="BlinkSlow" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="led4"
                    AutoReverse="True"
                    RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource RedOn}"/>
                <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="{StaticResource RedOn}"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="{StaticResource RedOff}"/>
                <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="{StaticResource RedOff}"/>
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>       
    </Window.Resources>

    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource BlinkSlow}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>

    <StackPanel x:Name="leds_container" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,20,4,0">
        <Ellipse x:Name="led1" Width="{StaticResource Diameter}" Height="{StaticResource Diameter}" Fill="#FFF90F0F" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
        <Ellipse x:Name="led2" Width="{StaticResource Diameter}" Height="{StaticResource Diameter}" Fill="#FFF90F0F" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
        <Ellipse x:Name="led3" Width="{StaticResource Diameter}" Height="{StaticResource Diameter}" Fill="#FFF90F0F" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
        <Ellipse x:Name="led4" Width="{StaticResource Diameter}" Height="{StaticResource Diameter}" Fill="#FFF90F0F" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Style-Triggers for that.

Create your storyboard in the Resources-section like you already did, but without a target name.

Then you create a style for your ellipse which includes a DataTrigger, starting the animation you need for your current state.

For example:

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <!--
    Other declarations
    -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=State, Mode=OneWay}" Value="BlinkSlow">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource BlinkSlow}" />
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
            <!--
            Add DataTrigger for your other states too.
            -->
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Gonna give it a try, looks like a good solution, as soon as I have new info I'll give feedback, thanks!

Comment: Would you mind to suggest how I am supposed to implement my ViewModel (to be used as DataContext)? Supposing I have my LedsPanelViewModel, with a property named "State", how should I set this property? With a string like this `this.State = "BlinkSlowState"` for example, or should I create an Enum? I am confused...

Comment: I did it, and it worked with the `Value` property being a string. Thank you very much!!

Comment: You can use an Enum too. It will work, because its handled as an integer internally. It will improve readability of your code, you should definitely use an Enum.